# Javascript - Removing array values between a range

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all the null values between the first number and the end number.

My code seems far too complicated.

Love to see some more flexible minds at it.

```js
let values = [null, null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5, 6, 7, null, null, null, null];

let startIndex = values.findIndex(n => (n !== null))

let endIndex = values.length - 1;
for ( ; endIndex > 0; endIndex--) {
  if (values[endIndex] !== null) break;
}

let arrayCopy = values.slice();

for(let i = endIndex; i > startIndex; i--) {
  if (values[i] === null) {
    arrayCopy.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(arrayCopy)
```

Comment: Not sure what start of the number and the end means...

Comment: You should try let newValues = values.filter( (int) => { return int != null } );

Comment: https://codepen.io/DanielTate/pen/baPdQJ?editors=0012

Comment: oh, you want only the nulls between non-nulls to be removed

Comment: Sorry, edited my terrible English.

Comment: What is `startIndex`, `endIndex` and the expected value of `arrayCopy`?

Comment: Expected value is as in my code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, sure it can be done better

```js
var values = [null, null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5, 6, 7, null, null, null, null];
var nonNull = values.filter(value => value !== null);
var result = [...values.slice(0, values.indexOf(nonNull[0])), ...nonNull, ...values.slice(values.lastIndexOf(nonNull[nonNull.length - 1]) + 1)];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: don't understand it either. Your code produces correct output Have an upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

I used a filter taking index or null values into account, it is certainly clearer IMO.

If your array is "very large", it might be interesting to find another way to compute the `endIndex`, but if you don't have performance problems, I think you can keep this part of your code as it is.

```js
let values = [null, null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5, 6, 7, null, null, null, null];

let startIndex = values.findIndex(n => (n !== null))
let endIndex = values.length - 1;
for ( ; endIndex > 0; endIndex--) {
  if (values[endIndex] !== null) break;
}

let arrayCopy = values.filter((v, i) => i < startIndex || i > endIndex || v !== null);

console.log(arrayCopy)
```

Comment: I like that filtering. Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This approach use reduce function to find the number of nulls in the at the start and at the end of the array, and then to add counted nulls before and after the non null elements.

```js
let values = [null, null, null, 1, 2, null, 3, null, 4, null, null, 5, 6, 7, null, null, null, null];
    
    var reduceFn = function(a,b){
      if (!a.finished && b === null){
        a.nullCount++;
      }
      if (b !== null){
        a.finished = true;
      }
      return a;
    };
    
    var start = {finished : false, nullCount:0};
    values.reduce(reduceFn,start);
    
    var end = {finished : false, nullCount:0};
    values.slice().reverse().reduce(reduceFn,end);
    
    result = Array(start.nullCount).fill(null);
    result.push.apply(result,values.filter(v => v !== null));
    result.push.apply(result,Array(end.nullCount).fill(null));
    
    
    console.log(result)
```